# XML Comment for C# function with out parameter

Tags: xml-comments

C# function with out parameter.

```
public static bool theFunction(string param1, out ulong param2) {
  param2 = 103206309L;
  return true;  
}
```

How is the out param2 properly denoted in an XML comment?

If you do the tripple slash in VS you get:

```
/// <summary>
/// theFunction that does cool stuff
/// </summary>
/// <param name="param1"></param>
/// <param name="param2"></param>
/// <returns>success or failure as bool</returns>
public static bool theFunction(string param1, out ulong param2) {
  param2 = 103206309L; 
  return true;  
}
```

But that isn't really clear if some document system like Swagger records everything and makes it's document available to informs the curious developer that it's a 'parameter' and... good luck with that! Unless Swagger also looks at the parameter definition in addition to the comments? I've tried to see if XML comments support more type or directional information, but I can't see anything like this?

If someone knows better, please respond.